# Signing Windows x64 drivers to work without the test mode enabled

Tags: windows, 64-bit, device-driver, drivers, signing

I would like to make my drivers to install on x64 Windows without the need to switch to Test Mode.   Could you please advise how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all here: [Driver Signing Requirements for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/drvsign/drvsign.mspx)

Warning: it costs money because you need a certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to Microsoft's whitepaper about the steps necessary for driver signing:
[Kernel Mode Code Signing Whitepaper](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/drvsign/kmcs_walkthrough.mspx)